# Making a vector of subvectors

Tags: c++

I am facing the following problem. Have a

```
std::vector<std::byte> vec
```

Of a large size, say something like `32*350000`. I need to get a

```
std::vector<std::array<std::byte,32>> vec32
```

Of length `350000` out of it, simply by collecting each consecutive 32 bytes from `vec`. I do not need `vec` anymore after I get `vec32` so the question is what's an efficient (both in memory and speed) way of getting `vec32`. The simplest way would be to do something like

```
vec32.reserve(vec.size())
```

And then copy each 32 bytes over vec32. At least this avoids resizing `vec32`.

Since `std::vector` are guaranteed to be contiguous in memory, would a simple

```
std::memcpy(&vec32.data(), &vec.data(), sizeof(vec))
```

work? and if so, would it be really better than the implementation copying each 32 bytes and using `vec32.push_back()`?

Finally, is there anyway of just moving over the data instead of copying it? In the sense that I would want to have something like the following pseudo-code assignment

```
vec32.data() = vec.data()
```

Comment: `vec32.reserve(sizeof(vec))` -- Whatever it is that you're thinking this does, it soesn't do what you think it does.  If you want to get the number of items in a vector, the way to do that is to use `vec.size()`.

Comment: Note: `vector::data` returns a pointer. No need for the `&`s in `std::memcpy(&vec32.data(), &vec.data(), sizeof(vec))`. In fact they're harmful.

Comment: A vector's operations are very fast, because the data lies in contiguous memory.  Are you sure you need to prematurely optimize here?  You should write the code without these concerns, create an optimized build of your application, and then measure.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie indeed I meant size(), just typed fast... Editing the question appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

`vec32.reserve(sizeof(vec))` will not work. `sizeof(vec)` is a constant, regardless of the number of bytes in `vec`. Also, `reserve` done on an empty `vector` results in a still-empty `vector` that can grow to the specified size without being reallocated. What you want is `vec32.resize(vec.size()/32)`.

You could `memmove` the whole `vector`, but that could result in portability issues. You're highly unlikely to have padding between `array<byte,32>` elements, but between `array<byte,23>` you probably will, and it's implementation dependent. So do `memmove(&vec32[i],&vec[i*32],32)` in a loop. Note that, unlike an array declared with `int vec[343]`, `&vec[0]` is not the same as `vec`!

Comment: I think `std::vector::reserve` (modulo the mistake of size() vs sizeof) does avoid the resizing of the vector which is the costly operation. `std::vector::resize` as suggested here  unnecessarily will default construct the elements which is something I want to avoid.

Comment: Yes, but then you have to `push_back` the elements. Copying bytes to a `vector` which has been reserved, but not resized, will write to memory that will then be overwritten if you `push_back` to the `vector`.

Comment: Sure, but `push_back` is just as effective as a `memcpy` on a loop if the memory has already been reserved as no resizing needs to be made. Resize on the other hand will unnecessarily create objects on the whole space and then after that overwrite it. I don't see any gain in `vec32.resize()`.